# What do I gain for completing weapon side-missions?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I have yet to complete any weapon side-mission chain, but I noticed that, after doing five missions for any weapon, the weapon screen pops up showing some runic writings appearing.

Is there any bonus my weapons gain at this point? If so, what is it?
What do I gain for completing a whole chain?

Comment: This might be purely me, but the actual model of the weapon changes every 5 and 10 missions. Personally I hated that the "dagger" was just a broken sword so having it reforged was quite nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By completing weapon side-missions, you gain Mirian (currency to upgrade stuff) and when you complete enough missions, the look of your weapons will change.

Some people mentioned, that you also get a few more execution animations and you break shields more easily, but that is only conjecture.

Sources:

[Gosunoob.com - Sword legend](http://www.gosunoob.com/shadow-of-mordor/sword-legends-missions-guide/)

[GameFAQs thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/739521-middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor/70220121)

Comment: In other words: You get nothing really. I was quite disappointed when I completed the bow missions, because I only got an inscription on it, so I can barely even see it. You only get the normal mission reward, but no reward that affects gameplay for completing all 10 missions. If there were more executions added, added shield breaking or such things there was definitely no hint given in-game upon completing the missions (at least for the bow).